# How to convert method.getGenericReturnType() to a jvm type signature

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

How to convert an instance of `java.lang.reflect.Type` into a jvm generic type signature?

```
Type type = method.getGenericReturnType();
String signature = toTypeSig(type);
```

For instance this Type:

```
Map<String, Map<?, ? super Integer>>
```

Must become this String:

```
"Ljava/util/Map<Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map<*-Ljava/lang/Integer;>;>;"
```

How do people using `orb.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter` solve this?

I've done it iterating over the Type information. 
But I'd prefer something more robust.
(I've posted my own solution as an answer because it's a bit long)

Comment: I'm curious. In which class file the type would not have been removed before because of the type erasure?

Comment: I have to pass an object instance to a library that will call: 
`object.getClass().getTypeParameters()`, and the type I want it to receive is defined at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. Every day there is something new to learn. ;-) Till now I wasn't aware about that.

Comment: In case someone is wondering what was that for: https://github.com/electronicarts/orbit/tree/master/utils/rest-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to get the jvm signature from a class file (or did you mean from a source file?)

From a class following could be a solution

```
public class GetSignature {

    // the method for which you want to retrieve the signature
    Map<String, Map<?, ? super Integer>> someMethod() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // make the private method in class Method accessible
        Method methodGenericSignature = Method.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                "getGenericSignature",
                (Class<?>[]) null
        );
        methodGenericSignature.setAccessible(true);

        // get the signature from the method
        Method method = GetSignature.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod",
                (Class<?>[]) null
        );
        String returnValue = (String) methodGenericSignature.invoke(method,
                (Object[]) null
        );
        System.out.println("signature: " + returnValue);
    }
}
```

output

```
signature: ()Ljava/util/Map<Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map<*-Ljava/lang/Integer;>;>;
```

**edit** A small snipped to demonstrate how to get the signature using [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/).

```
public class GetSignatureDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/tmp/GetSignature.class");
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(is);
        classReader.accept(getClassVisitor(), 0);
    }

    private static ClassVisitor getClassVisitor() {
        return new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {
            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name,
                    String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "method: %s  descriptor: %s  signature: %s%n",
                        name,
                        descriptor,
                        signature
                );
                return super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

sample output

```
method: someMethod  descriptor: ()Ljava/util/Map;  signature: ()Ljava/util/Map<Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map<*-Ljava/lang/Integer;>;>;
```

Comment: That's great! I have a test case that uses asm.ClassVisitor to validate the generated signature and your solution passes all my 25 tests. I'll post my own solution here for reference but I'll actually use yours.

Comment: Though, if you have such a method and are going to use ASM anyway, reading the class file directly using ASM instead of hacking into Reflection internals is straight-forward…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the comment. I've added a second snippet demonstrating how to get the signature using asm directly.

Comment: @Holger, not really the method might be generated by another library and its class file might not be available.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution. I'm posting for reference. Since it might be useful when `method.setAccessible(true)` is not available.

This is more or less what I ended up using.
Because I needed to transform the generic return type into a class signature. And I had no use for the type variables.

It works well for methods without type parameters. 
For methods with generic type parameters it tries to replace the parameters.

Processing the generic return type of this method: `<P> List<P> someMethod()` 
results in `"Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/Object;>;"`

```
static String toGenericSignature(final Type type)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    toGenericSignature(sb, type);
    return sb.toString();
}

static void toGenericSignature(StringBuilder sb, final Type type)
{
    if (type instanceof GenericArrayType)
    {
        sb.append("[");
        toGenericSignature(sb, ((GenericArrayType) type).getGenericComponentType());
    }
    else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType)
    {
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) type;
        sb.append('L');
        sb.append(((Class) pt.getRawType()).getName().replace('.', '/'));
        sb.append('<');
        for (Type p : pt.getActualTypeArguments())
        {
            toGenericSignature(sb, p);
        }
        sb.append(">;");
    }
    else if (type instanceof Class)
    {
        Class clazz = (Class) type;
        if (!clazz.isPrimitive() && !clazz.isArray())
        {
            sb.append('L');
            sb.append(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/'));
            sb.append(';');
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/'));
        }
    }
    else if (type instanceof WildcardType)
    {
        WildcardType wc = (WildcardType) type;
        Type[] lowerBounds = wc.getLowerBounds();
        Type[] upperBounds = wc.getUpperBounds();
        boolean hasLower = lowerBounds != null && lowerBounds.length > 0;
        boolean hasUpper = upperBounds != null && upperBounds.length > 0;

        if (hasUpper && hasLower && Object.class.equals(lowerBounds[0]) && Object.class.equals(upperBounds[0]))
        {
            sb.append('*');
        }
        else if (hasLower)
        {
            sb.append("-");
            for (Type b : lowerBounds)
            {
                toGenericSignature(sb, b);
            }
        }
        else if (hasUpper)
        {
            if (upperBounds.length == 1 && Object.class.equals(upperBounds[0]))
            {
                sb.append("*");
            }
            else
            {
                sb.append("+");
                for (Type b : upperBounds)
                {
                    toGenericSignature(sb, b);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append('*');
        }
    }
    else if (type instanceof TypeVariable)
    {
        //sb.append("T");
        //sb.append(((TypeVariable) type).getName());
        //sb.append(";");
        // work around: replaces the type variable with it's first bound.
        toGenericSignature(sb, ((TypeVariable) type).getBounds()[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type: " + type);
    }
}
```

Comment: In your loop over the type arguments you are saying `if (p instanceof Class) toGenericSignature(sb, p); else toGenericSignature(sb, p);` which obviously can be simplified to `toGenericSignature(sb, p);` as the test has no effect when you are doing exactly the same in both cases…